# Вывод вещественных чисел с использованием запятой

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как можно вывести число float или double с разделяющей запятой вместо точки? Гуглил, и предполагаю, что делается это при помощи setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "что_то_там"), но не знаю, что именно за локаль нужно подключить. Или, может, локаль не разрешит эту задачу и требуется делать что-то другое?

Comment: Да, локаль управляет таким форматированием. Если нужно выводить независимо от локали, то я бы делал sprintf в буфер, менял точки на запятые и потом выводил буфер (как строку).

Comment: а если делать с использованием локали?

Comment: Попробуйте локаль "" (пустую строку).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В С++ потоках это можно сделать, не трогая все остальные характеристики локали. Предположим, мы хотим поправить локаль потока cout (в С++ можно потокам назначать разные локали, в отличие от С).

Делаем новый класс фацета

```
#include <locale>

class comma : public numpunct<char> {
    public:
        comma () : numpunct<char> () {}
    protected:
    char do_decimal_point() const {
        return ',';
    }
};
```

Далее получаем текущую локаль cout, создаем на ее основе новую локаль с фацетом comma и назначаем ее cout

```
locale loccomma (cout.getloc(), new comma); 
cout.imbue (loccomma);
```

Проверяем

```
cout << 33.22 << endl;
```

Должны получить

```
33,22
```

Чтобы назначить новую локаль всем будущим потокам, делаем так:

```
locale::global (loccomma);
```

Все новосозданные потоки будут иметь эту локаль.

Comment: @mikillskegg, восхищаюсь. Неужели Вы помните все методы всех классов, от которых `cout` наследуется?

Comment: Ну, вообще-то тут ни слова не было сказано о предках cout. Конечно, я не все помню. Но я помню, где можно подсмотреть нужную информацию.

Comment: Как же не было, а

    cout.imbue (loccomma);

это ведь метод у ios_base (базовый). Но я просто посмотрел [через гугл](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/) после Вашего ответа.

Сам-то ничего такого не помню.

Answer (score 0):

[@MorkOFF48](/users/9000/morkoff48), я попробовал в линуксе, получилось

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main ()
{
  struct lconv *lc, slc;
  struct tm    *tm;

  char *p = setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);
  char buf[1024];

  printf ("initial %s\n",p);
  printf ("%lf\n",3.14);

  p = setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
  printf ("setlocale(\"\") %s\n",p);
  p = setlocale(LC_ALL,NULL);
  printf ("NULL %s\n",p);

  printf ("%lf\n",3.14);

}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc loca.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
initial C
3.140000
setlocale("") ru_RU.utf8
NULL ru_RU.utf8
3,140000
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Если менять только для вывода чисел, то вместо `LC_ALL` надо вызывать `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"")`
(`""` - это локаль по умолчанию).

Если по умолчанию не годится, то попробуйте `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"ru_RU.utf8");`, но какая именно Вам подойдет, не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно написать отдельную функцию. (Я никогда не доверял этим локалям, они кажутся мне подозрительными :) )

```
#include "stdio.h"
char loc=',';

void printf_f(double d){
    printf("%d%c%d", (int)d, loc, int((d-(int)d)*1000000));
}

int main(){
    printf_f(12345.67890);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, раз уж дело дошло до написания велосипедов, то предлагаю более простой (велосипед, имею в виду)

 char a[30];
 sprintf (a, "%f", 92.222); 
 char* p = strchr (a, '.');
 if (p) *p=',';
 printf ("%s\n", a);

Comment: Вариант @mikelsv намного быстрей :)

Comment: Очень может быть... Тестировали или так прикинули?

Comment: Навскидку, без оптимизации и включения головы: http://pastebin.com/xYJyTquQ

a1: 17, a2: 1

Comment: У тебя в коде ошибка. Второе присвоение значения переменной j стоит не на том месте )). По моим замерам оба варианта работают примерно одинаково. Но по-любому, это не серьезный способ решить задачу.

Comment: Тьху, блин. Вот нутром понимаю, что printf медленней должно быть :) Переставил на место - наоборот получается, 14/19. Правда, под рукой OpenWatcom только...

Comment: @mikelsv, а что Вы будете делать с форматами e или g? 

Я бы предложил что-то в таком духе

    char *
    pricomma (double v, char *fmt, char *buf) 
    {
        sprintf(buf,fmt,v);
        char *p = strchr(buf,'.');
        if (p) 
           *p = ',';
        return buf;
    }

Только набив, увидел, что такой вариант уже @mikillskegg предложил

Comment: Мой вариант заточен под конкретный тип. Честно говоря я кажется ни разу не пользовался e и g. Замена подходит для всех вариантов, но для нее нужна память. Выделить побольше памяти в стеке и будет счастье.

a1: 14 a2: 3. Разница чуть больше чем в 4 раза.

Comment: @mikelsv, @klopp, просто на будущее. От оптимизации этой программы скорость практически не зависит. А время  стоит измерять в сотых секунды (интервал системного таймера 0.01 сек).

У меня получилось

    (/ (+ 6457 6474 6561 6801 6566 6827 6514) (+ 1729 1551 1548 1597 1613 1546 1536 .0))
4.154676258992806

это замеры в миллисекундах

Comment: @avp, я что-то ничего не понял.

Comment: Взял программу из пастебина. Чуть поправил и заменил printf на fprintf(stderr,...), вставил свою mtime() (время в миллисекундах), 5 раз запустил (>/dev/null), перетранслировал с -O3, перекинул цифры вывода в Emacs, расставил скобочки и операции, скопипастил сюда.

Получил отношение времени sprintf,strchr,printf к printf("%d%c%d",...

Comment: Правда, под рукой OpenWatcom только 

dos-фанат, однако? Тогда защита peekb становится понятней...

Comment: Кроме DOS есть ещё и нетварь, которую долго приходилось поддерживать. А защищаю я не peekb, а право человека на самоопределение и отсутствие непрошеных советов :) Один хрен - сколько не долби, всем нужно свои  шишки набить, что зря время терять?